# What could cause a 400 Bad Request when publishing to npm?

Tags: npm

Running into an issue today publishing npm. This worked ok for me the other day but today I'm getting this relevant portion of the log.

```
33 notice shasum:        9c4a2518ad868612345bf7c9dbb9e9d8e85aa4ea
33 notice integrity:     sha512-n1mlshzLfrmSY[...]Xw1ESWu2jL2Jg==
33 notice total files:   390
34 notice
35 timing command:publish Completed in 924ms
36 verbose stack HttpErrorGeneral: 400 Bad Request - PUT http://registry.npmjs.org/ids$
36 verbose stack     at /Users/tmcconechy/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules$
36 verbose stack     at async publish (/Users/tmcconechy/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/l$
36 verbose stack     at async Publish.publish (/Users/tmcconechy/.nvm/versions/node/v1$
37 verbose statusCode 400
38 verbose pkgid ids-enterprise-wc@0.0.0-beta.11
39 verbose cwd /Users/tmcconechy/Dev/enterprise-wc2/dist
40 verbose Darwin 20.4.0
41 verbose argv "/Users/tmcconechy/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node" "/Users/tmcco$
42 verbose node v14.16.0
43 verbose npm  v7.11.2
44 error code E400
45 error 400 Bad Request - PUT http://registry.npmjs.org/ids-enterprise-wc
46 verbose exit 1
```

I tried `npm login` and a few other things but just not understanding what this could be. It happens in 5 different repos i work on...

Any suggestions?

Comment: I got this error when i have 'hacker' word on my package name. When i change it to something else, `npm publish` works fine. So I think maybe the problem is the `ids-enterprise-wc` package name not allowed by npm because of someone's else trademark, etc.  https://docs.npmjs.com/package-name-guidelines